# How to find the next record in a table with no value yet?

Tags: ms-access-2007

Need Help in **Access**. Maybe it's simple and very easy for you but I can't figure out how to do this. I'm not really familiar with this, just trying to create simple application for `in/out`. How to find the next record with no Sign-out yet? My query always just looking for the first record, I want it to go for the next record with null Sign-out.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the Table.

```
Log Number  Staff Number    Sign-in  Sign-out
1   65294   3/6/2013 4:02:29 PM 3/7/2013 7:33:26 AM
2   007 3/6/2013 4:02:33 PM 3/7/2013 7:40:18 AM
3   4006381333627   3/6/2013 4:02:37 PM 3/7/2013 7:33:06 AM
4   4005401881216   3/6/2013 4:02:40 PM 3/7/2013 7:33:12 AM
5   4006381333689   3/6/2013 4:02:44 PM 3/7/2013 7:33:02 AM
34  007 3/7/2013 4:33:35 AM
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Combo18_Click()
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone

rs.FindFirst "[Log Number] = " & Str(Nz(Me![Combo18], 0))

If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark

If IsNull(Sign_out) Then
    Me.Sign_out.Value = Now()
    End If

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Me.Combo18.SetFocus
Me!Combo18 = Null

End Sub
```